# How to ensure django serves template in new tab after processing the post request params?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I have a button in my html that when clicked does some calculations and makes a `post` call to one of my API with some params and then from `django` I fetch the params and put them in the specific placeholders of the template and render the template.

The problem is I can see the template being rendered (if I check the 'network' section of `Google inspect element`) but I don't see anything in the page. I expect the template to be rendered in a new tab with the values I fetched from the `post` params placed in respective placeholders in the template.

Here is what I send through `ajax post` (I am using `angular js` in my project but I can also do it with plain js too)

```
var toSend = {
            "user": username,
            "password": password,
            "text": text
            "context": $scope.newContext,
    }


$http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/correction',
          data: toSend
        }).
        then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.data);
  })
```

Here is my `django` function defined for the API which receives the `post` request

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_correction(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
                context = {}
                try:
                        print("recieved request")
                        user_request = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
                        '''
                        some logic I use to check given the 
                        username and password, whether it is a 
                        valid user or not
                        '''
                        text_header = user_request.get("text")
                        userid = user_request.get("user")

                        context["userid"] = userid
                        context["text_header"] = text_header

                except Exception as e:
                        print(e)

                return render(request, 'correction_page.html', context)
```

Here I store the text and user in a `context` dictionary to be sent along with the `correction_page.html`.

Here is how my correction page looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <span> {{text_header}} </span>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/fetch_info.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Here the `text_header` placeholder indeed gets the value (as I can see in `Google chrome` network section in inspect element.)

But in the UI, I do not see anything happening. I was hoping that the template would be served in a new tab but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you expect that to happen? Your ajax call does nothing with the returned data apart from logging it to the console.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes that is why I was looking at other ways of send post request which would open the content in a new tab.

Comment: You shouldn't be using ajax if you expect page to do a full refresh after the response is returned. AJAX enables you to do quite the opposite – send a request without reloading a page.  The role of forms in client-side AngularJS applications is different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is desirable for the browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload that sends the data to the server. Instead POST JSON data and receive JSON data as a response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

*Django is server-side, opening in a new tab is client-side. So, you wont be able to open in new tab just by server response. You need to handle it in client side , i.e. angularJS*

Make `$http` call, and once resolved, open a new tab and redirects to `/correction/data` which should provide all these data and return a `template` with necessary data , which have been saved after doing `POST` to `/correction`

something like:

```
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/correction',
      data: toSend
    }).
    then(function(response) {
       $window.open(url , '_blank');
})
```

and this `url` would refer to `/correction/data` and you'll get your data

Comment: hey sorry but it didn't work out for me though..in the end I had to make it work with a GET request.